# Start a countdown in a specific time depending on my video timer and pause the countdown when the video is paused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have a countdown and a video in my page. I want to start the countdown in a specific time depending to the video timer and pause my countdown when the video is paused.
Here is my actual code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
   document.getElementById('timer1').innerHTML = 7 + ":" + 55;
   startTimer();
   

            

            function startTimer() {
                var presentTime = document.getElementById('timer1').innerHTML;
                var timeArray = presentTime.split(/[:]+/);
                var m = timeArray[0];
                var s = checkSecond((timeArray[1] - 1));
                if (s == 59) {
                    m = m - 1
                }


                document.getElementById('timer1').innerHTML =
                    "0" + (m < 10 ? m-- : "") + ":" + s;
                setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
            }

            function checkSecond(sec) {
                if (sec < 10 && sec >= 0) {
                    sec = "0" + sec
                }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
                if (sec < 0) {
                    sec = "59"
                };
                return sec;
            }
        });

 var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");

    function playPause() {
        if (myVideo.paused)
            myVideo.play();
        else
            myVideo.pause();
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video1">
<source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>


<div class="inline_timer hidden" id="element_1" align="center">
   <h3><span id="timer1"></span><span> The MASSIVE Thyroid Secret Is Revealed...</span></h3>
        
</div>
```

Can anyone help me figured it out please?

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924822(v=vs.85).aspx) web site, I write the following coding, it works in Edge, Chrome and Firefox!

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var video;
        var timer;
        var vLength=3*60+55; 
        $(document).ready(function() {
                    video=$("#video1");
                    timer=$("#timer1");
                    video.on("click",function (){
                                        if (this.paused)
                                            this.play();
                                        else
                                            this.pause();
                                    });
                    video.on("timeupdate",function()
                                        {

                                            vTime=this.currentTime.toFixed(0);
                                            vRemaining=(vLength - vTime);
                                            sec=vRemaining%60;
                                            min=(vRemaining-sec)/60;
                                            vRemaining=min+":"+sec;
                                            timer.text(vRemaining);
                                        }); 
                });
        </script>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id="video1" autoplay>
        <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="inline_timer hidden" id="element_1" align="center">
        <h3><span id="timer1">3:55</span><span> The MASSIVE Thyroid Secret Is Revealed...</span></h3>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you comment the code please? I'm not sure that the video.on function helped me the way that I want.

Comment: After a video starts playing, you can use the ontimeupdate event to get the current position in a video. The ontimeupdate event fires when the currentTime property changes.The currentTime property return the current playback position, in seconds, whereas the duration property return a floating point number that represents the duration of the current media resource in seconds. So, we can use these 2 property to calculate the remaining time of the video. It should fullfill your need.

Comment: `document.getElementById('video1').addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
                if (this.currentTime > 235) {
                    document.getElementById('timer1').innerHTML = 7 + ":" + 55;
                    startTimer();
                }

            });` it works in this way but the timer speed up

Comment: I wonder you have include jquery lib. why you not use jquery to add event listener?
May be I misunderstand what you need.

Comment: I tested your code and I've seen that you've use the video length as timer. My case is different, I have a timer with 7:55 of lengh and has to be started after 3:55 of my video current time. And need when the video is paused, the timer to be paused to

Comment: I have update the above coding accordingly. However, would you elaborate in more detail about "has to be started after 3:55 of my video current time"?
Do you mean when user scroll to 0:00 and then click the play button, the video player start to play the video at 3:55?

Comment: no, there is a countdown and an auto play video. The countdown shows up exactly at 3:55 of video reading.
This part is already done but I've noticed that even the countdown shows up at 3:55, it start at the page loading which not what I want. Now I want the countdown to start at the same time it suppose to show up and be paused when the video is paused. Remember, the countdown has it's own length

Comment: According to your description and code, the video player does not show the control, how you pause the video?

Comment: I have a function to allow the pause by clicking on the video

Comment: Would you append the function to the above coding?

Comment: Just added the function!

Comment: Base on my understanding, I updated my coding accordingly, please check.
In fact, I don't know why you use the following statement.

setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);